# Book where boy teleports to another world/dimension but doesn’t know how; fights a wild boar

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Orange/yellow book cover.

Boy somehow teleports to a different world or dimension but doesn’t remember how he got there, just wakes up to find himself somewhere else. Fights a wild boar or hog. It may be a bear, wife says she thinks it has to do with a kid playing soccer and gets knocked out and wakes up in different world.

Comment: Do you actually mean that this is a [fighting fantasy gamebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_Fantasy)?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Possibly a bear?

Answer (score 3):

This may be Gary Paulsen's *The Transall Saga*. The boar is mentioned in [this review](https://freecustomwritings.com/the-transall-saga):

> In the beginning of the story, Mark is on a camping trip in the desert. He is with his parents, who are adventurers and he is having a great time. He is roaming along through the desert at night by when he spots a strange blue light shining from the skies. He climbs a rock to get a better view of this light, when the rock slides and he falls off into the light. When he wakes up he is stunned to find that he is no longer in the desert.

....

> When food becomes a problem for Mark he goes out on a search and kills a big boar creature. This boar creature was attacking human looking animal so Mark killed it. Mark realizes that there are other human like creatures on the planet and he follows the girl to her tribe.

Most of the covers are indeed orange/yellow in coloration:
[image: Cover of *The Transall Saga*]

Comment: No I dont think that is the book, but thank you for your input

Comment: @Alexander: What are the ways it does not match? :) Indicating why answers are not correct might just be a matter of "I know I've never read that book", but more often, it's "I've read that book and it doesn't match because of X and Y, and because I know Z wasn't present", which is helpful to add to your question.